# Why this if else condition is not working properly?

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I am using if else condition with foreach loop to check and insert new tags.

but both the conditions(if and alse) are being applied at the same time  irrespective of wether the mysql found id is equal or not equal to the foreach posted ID.  Plz help

```
$new_tags = $_POST['new_tags'];   //forget the mysl security for the time being   

foreach ($new_tags as $fnew_tags)
{
    $sqlq = mysqli_query($db3->connection, "select * from  o4_tags limit 1");
    while($rowq = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlq)) {
        $id = $rowq['id'];

        if($id == $fnew_tags) {    //if  ID  of the tag is matched then do not insert  the new tags but only add the user refrence to that  ID
            mysqli_query($db3->connection, "insert into user_interests(uid,tag_name,exp_tags) values('$session->userid','$fnew_tags','1')");
        } 
        else 
        {   //if  ID  of the tag is not  matched then  insert  the new tags as well as  add the user refrence to that  ID
            $r = mysqli_query($db3->connection, "insert into o4_tags(tag_name,ug_tags,exp_tags) values('$fnew_tags','1','1')");
            $mid_ne = mysqli_insert_id($db3->connection);
            mysqli_query($db3->connection, "insert into user_interests(uid,tag_name,exp_tags) values('$session->userid','$mid_ne','1')");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that both parts of if/else are actually executed. Try to just print something in console instead of your queries, it most likely an error in code inside if/else.

Comment: try to print $id  $fnew_tags values before checking

Answer (score 0):

i think you are inserting

```
 $r = mysqli_query($db3->connection, "insert into o4_tags(tag_name,ug_tags,exp_tags)
 values('$fnew_tags','1','1')");$mid_ne = mysqli_insert_id($db3->connection);
```

and then you are using   `while($rowq = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlq))`

which now has records you just inserted therefore your if is executed

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the `select` query below will always return the same record.

```
$sqlq = mysqli_query($db3->connection, "select * from  o4_tags limit 1");
```

I think most of the time it will goes to the `else`, which execute the 2 insert.
Shouldn't you write the query like below?

```
select * from  o4_tags where id = $fnew_tags limit 1
```